# How to perform commandLink's action method before filedownload in commandLink?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

codes:

```
<p:dialog header="Downloads" widgetVar="hwDialog" modal="true"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false"
    appendTo="@(body)" width="700" height="500" position="center center">

    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{MB.selectedReset()}"
        update="@([id$=hwTable])" />

    <h:form id="dlg_form">
        <p:dataTable id="dlg_hwTable" var="std"
            value="#{MB.list}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{std.id}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowIndexVar="count">



            <p:column headerText="File">
                <p:commandLink ajax="false" value="Download"
                    action="#{MB.prepareForDownload(std)}">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{MB.file}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

file is null **at the first click** in p:filedownload.Then dialog closes unexpectedly.Unexpectedly because close event doesn't work when the dialog closed.But I am re-opening dialog and clicking the link again.Works but downloading previous file.So filedownload performed before commandLink's action method.How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `actionListener` to prepare a file stream for `p:fileDownload`, because the `action` method gets triggered after the downloading logic executes.
This will fix the dissappearing dialog too - it was happening because without a file the download request resulted in a non-AJAXical POST navigation, which basically resets the page DOM to its initial state.